# HTML table not appearing as expected

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, css, tabular

My table has two menus, a normal menu and a sub menu but when changing the tab and in the sub menu choose any option the first text is not hidden both are displayed and if we go to the 3 tab are finished by showing the three where I have the error or any solution that I can give?

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8" />
       <title>Eventos</title>
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
       <meta name="description" content="" />
       <meta name="author" content="" />
        <?php require_once('resources/head.php'); ?>
     <!--Zona de estilos -->
       <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/menu.css">
       <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/menu2.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="loader"></div>
        <div id="wrapper" class="wrapper-container">
            <?php require_once('resources/header.php'); ?>
            
            <div id="content">
                <div class="breadcrumbs-wrap style-2">
                    <div class="container">
                        <h1 class="page-title"><span style="color: #FFF;">Eventos</span></h1>
                        <ul class="breadcrumbs">
                            <li><span style="color: #FFF;">Inicio / Eventos</span></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <
                <!--AQUI TERMINA EL ENCABEZADO NO BORRAR NADA HACIA ARRIBA-->
                <!--you shall not pass-->

                <!--empieza la zona del contenido-->

               <div class="container">
<!--Primera seccion de talleres-->
<!--menu de arranque  inicio-->
    <div id="content">
      <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#semana1" data-toggle="tab">taller1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#semana2" data-toggle="tab">taller2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#semana3" data-toggle="tab">taller3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
 <!--menu de arranque final-->
  <!--inicio de submenu 1-->
    <div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="semana1">
         <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
         <li class="active"><a href="#1semana1" data-toggle="tab">Semana 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#1semana2" data-toggle="tab">Semana 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#1semana3" data-toggle="tab">Semana 3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#1semana4" data-toggle="tab">Semana4</a>
        </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
  <!--final de submenu 1-->
  <!--inicio de submenu 2-->
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="semana2">
         <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
         <li class="active"><a href="#2semana1" data-toggle="tab">Semana 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#2semana2" data-toggle="tab">Semana 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#2semana3" data-toggle="tab">Semana 3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#2semana4" data-toggle="tab">Semana 4</a>
        </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
       <!--final de submenu 2-->
       <!--inicio de submenu 3-->
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="semana3">
         <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#3semana1" data-toggle="tab">Semana 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#3semana2" data-toggle="tab">Semana 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#3semana3" data-toggle="tab">Semana 3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#3semana4" data-toggle="tab">Semana 4</a>
        </li>
         </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
       <!--final de submenu 3-->
       <!--INICIA ZONA DE CONTENIDOS-->
       <!--taller 1-->
   <div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="1semana1">
        <h1> Taller 1 / Semana 1</h1>
  
       <p>Jueves 11 oct </p>
• Agua de avena.
• Soufflé de papa( papas rebanadas, jamón de pechuga de pavo, crema Alpura Deslactosada y queso anela)(al horno )(favor de enviar 4 porciones sin queso y crema) 
• Fruta dela estación picada 
Bruno
         <p>Viernes 12 oct </p> 
<p>• Leche con chocolate frio( favor de enviar 4 porciones con leche de alimendras o soya o arroz). </p>
<p>• Ensalada de manzana, piña de almíbar en cubitos, zanahoria rayada con crema deslactosada alpura, el almíbar de la piña y nueces picadas (favor de enviar 4 porciones sin crema)</p>
<p>Jorge Alonso</p> 
          
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="1semana2">
        <h1>Orange</h1>
        <p>orange orange orange orange orange</p>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="1semana3">
        <h1>Yellow</h1>
        <p>yellow yellow yellow yellow yellow</p>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="1semana4">
        <h1>Green</h1>
        <p>green green green green green</p>
      </div>
    </div>
<!--fin de taller 1-->
<!--inicio de taller 2-->
    <div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane inactive" id="2semana1">
        <h1>Red</h1>
        <p>red red red red red red</p>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="2semana2">
        <h1>Orange</h1>
        <p>orange orange orange orange orange</p>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="2semana3">
        <h1>Yellow</h1>
        <p>yellow yellow yellow yellow yellow</p>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="2semana4">
        <h1>Green</h1>
        <p>green green green green green</p>
      </div>
    </div>
<!--fin de taller 2-->
<!--inicio de taller 3-->
    <div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane inactive" id="3semana1">
        <h1>Red</h1>
        <p>red red red red red red</p>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id=3semana2">
        <h1>Orange</h1>
        <p>orange orange orange orange orange</p>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="3semana3">
        <h1>Yellow</h1>
        <p>yellow yellow yellow yellow yellow</p>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="3semana4">
        <h1>Green</h1>
        <p>green green green green green</p>
      </div>
    </div>
<!--fin de taller 3-->
         <!--Termina zona de contenido-->
         <!-- NO BORRAR MAS AYA DE ESTE PUNTO -->
         <!--you shall not pass-->      
                   </div>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                   <div class="content__wrapper">
                    
                   </div>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                   <div class="content__wrapper">
                    
                   </div>
                  </li>
                 </ul>
                </section>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- zona de scripts-->
            <?php require_once('resources/footer.php'); ?>
        </div>
            <?php require_once('resources/scripts.php'); ?>
        <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script  src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
        <script  src="js/menu/index.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Edit your title please.

Comment: I am not seeing any tables here, are you confusing tables with tabs?